# MySQL: Improve query with conditional joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT n.type, n.type_id, n.data,
( CASE WHEN (n.type='users') THEN users.u_name ELSE NULL END ) AS user_name,
( CASE WHEN (n.type='blogs') THEN blogs.b_name ELSE NULL END ) AS blog_name
FROM notifications AS n
LEFT JOIN users ON ( CASE
                     WHEN (n.type='users') AND n.type_id=users.id THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                     END = 1 )
LEFT JOIN blogs ON ( CASE 
                     WHEN (n.type='blogs') AND n.type_id=blogs.id THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                     END = 1 )
WHERE n.receiver_id = 1
ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT 20
```

It works, but uses: Using temporary; Using filesort, Using join buffer (flat, BNL join), Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join). That does not look good.

Further more, the LEFT Joins should be INNER, but with inner it does not show any result... (and the same temporarys, filesorts, buffers, etc)

I tryied a different syntax (probably wrong) with same results:

```
 ( CASE WHEN (n.type='blogs') THEN n.type_id=blogs.id ELSE NULL END )
```

I could do two queries, but i'm trying to do it in one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT n.type, n.type_id, n.data,
       users.u_name as user_name,
       blogs.b_name AS blog_name
FROM notifications AS n
LEFT JOIN users ON n.type='users' AND n.type_id=users.id 
LEFT JOIN blogs ON n.type='blogs' AND n.type_id=blogs.id
WHERE n.receiver_id = 1
ORDER BY n.id DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

You don't need the cases. And `left join` is the right approach since a notification is either from users or blogs and not both.

Comment: It gives me no results and "Extra: Impossible WHERE" and all other explain fields NULL.

Comment: Thats really odd. Please add example data and expected output to your question.

Comment: The n.type can be different than user or blog, can be from actions that does not require any user or blog name

Comment: Ok I was using INNER, LEFT works I will test it a bit more.

Comment: I understant that if first condition n.type='users' is not meet, it does not search anything on the users table, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try below query :

This uses inner join and straight forward join conditions. 
Please note, there is one extra column n.id in the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT  n.id, n.type, n.type_id, n.data, u.u_name AS user_name, NULL AS blog_name
FROM    notification n INNER JOIN users u ON n.receiver_id = 1 AND n.type = 'users' AND n.type_id = u.id
UNION ALL
SELECT  n.id, n.type, n.type_id, n.data, NULL AS user_name, b.b_name AS blog_name
FROM    notification n INNER JOIN blogs b ON n.receiver_id = 1 AND n.type = 'blogs' AND n.type_id = b.id
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT n.type, n.type_id, n.data, 
  (select u.u_name from users as u where u.id = n.type_id and n.type = 'users'), 
  (select b.b_name from blogs as b where b.id = n.type_id and n.type = 'blogs')
FROM notifications AS n
WHERE n.receiver_id = 1
ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT 20
```